# how to determine no of requests in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, newrelic, puma

we are running **rails** app in production (single master node) with **nginx** as web and **puma** as rack server and wanted to calculate no of request our server can handle. I know there are tools available like [ApacheBench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench) which works like

```
ab -k -c 350 -n 20000 example.com
```

It takes few parameters like in above command 350 simultaneous connections until 20 thousand requests. This approach can give req per seconds count for a single URL. But, I am interested in determining request per seconds for dynamic system which serves dynamic content.

Is there any built-in tool which can give me request per second count.

**Way Around (Manual Calculations)**

I have installed an Analytics tool [rorvswild](https://www.rorvswild.com/) it is very similar to [NewRelic](https://newrelic.com/). It gives me response time of every route I have in ruby on rails application. It also gave average response time of all the routes, which is ***250ms*** If average response time of system is ***T*** can I calculate no of request system can handle will be 1000/T?

Also I am running puma behind NGINX, which is multithreaded and running 5 threads so eventually

no of requests per second = thread_count * (1000/T)

In my case thread_count = 5

Thank You so much for reading, you suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. `ab` doesn't care whether your content is static or dynamic.

Comment: @Stefan what I understand about 'ab' it takes a URL and hit on it, it doesn't care about all the URL in the system

Comment: You could benchmark the fastest (cheapest) and slowest (most expensive) page (or URL) to get a best case / worst case value.